# Is there a self hosted solution similar to Uservoice?

Tags: user-engagement

In the early days of Stack Overflow, [Uservoice](http://uservoice.com/) was used to get feedback, bug reports and feature requests from the community. While SO did out grow Uservoice, many sites would not.

I'd like to use a system very much like Uservoice for a site that I am launching. The problem is, I really prefer to host all moving parts myself.

I don't care if its free or proprietary, I just need something that will work on a typical Linux server.

Can anyone suggest something?

**Edit**

I want something self hosted because:

- Privacy is a major concern for my users
- I'd like to `programmatically` reward participation on the 'uservoice' with rewards on the actual site (ideally, that's just a few queries away)
- I'd like to be able to change the 'rules' on the 'uservoice' site if needed, but its not a major requirement.
- I trust my own backups more than anyone else's :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I remembered seeing a similar question to this on StackOverflow.. dredged it up, and found an interesting lead there called VoxPopuli http://www.eldos.com/vp/ which sounds pretty much like what you're looking for. It's probably not as polished as Uservoice or GetSatisfaction though.

Don't forget to upvote Eugene Mayevski at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576935/open-source-alternative-to-uservoice-or-get-satisfaction if this helped you :)

Comment: You can actually link to answers directly, for instance this one is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576935/open-source-alternative-to-uservoice-or-get-satisfaction/1734354#1734354

And yes, I up-voted his answer, wish I could up-vote you twice for not only giving credit but really working to provide an answer.

Comment: Tim, thanks for the kind words. Could you show the syntax to do that linking? I can see the result now, but am no closer to figuring out how you did that... :)

Comment: simply use the `link` tag next to flag below each of the answers. That will provide the link specific to that answer.

Answer (score 6):

According to [VentureBeats](http://venturebeatprofiles.com/company/profile/uservoice/competitors), Uservoice has 3 main competitors still running.  They are [CrowdSound](http://crowdsound.com/), [GetSatisfaction](http://getsatisfaction.com/), and [FeedbackFX](http://www.feedbackfx.com/).  Unfortunately, they all use the SaaS model as well so they won't solve you problem.

A quick look on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) and I found that there were 2 project but neither of them have been started.

I looked on [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/) and I found that there is a project to add Feedback to DotNetNuke, here http://dnnfeedback.codeplex.com/.  This might do what you want but it would probably only work on Linux if you have Mono installed.

Having looked into this, I think your best bet is to either use one of the tools like Uservoice or one of their competitors.  Also note, CrowdSound lets you tightly integrate their Saas by using their modules within your site.  Or you will need to write you own code.

Finally, ask yourself what value are you getting from hosting it yourself?  Will it easier to do your work or will it keep your data private.  If not then maybe hosting it yourself doesn't have a ton of value.

Comment: Privacy is a big concern for my users, I also want to be able to programatically reward participation on the 'uservoice' with rewards on the site, which is (usually) just a few queries away with a self hosted solution. Sure, I've been burned with SAAS data loss before, but its not my primary objection to using it in this case.

Comment: I also appreciate you looking. I've also been searching around for a while, but have not found anything.

Comment: @Tim - Your welcome.  I thought maybe you would be looking for privacy. The votes makes sense as well.

Comment: CrowdSound & FeedbackFX seem to be no longer alive. At least your links lead nowhere.